# clock rotating 360 degrees not working

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have an image of a clock, and I want it to be rotating 360 degrees with the help of css. However, even though I have the `transform: rotate(360deg)` property, my clock is still not rotating.

Here is my basic code.

***HTML***

```
<div id="clock"></div>
```

***CSS***

```
#clock {
    border-radius: 100px;
    height: 79px;
    width: 79px;
    background: url('https://s3.postimg.io/3k6hhoafn/download.png');
}
#clock:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

I have a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8j900hz0/) that shows how my clock should look like.

Please explain why my clock is not rotating and fix the error.

Comment: Your clock is rotating 360°! You just don't see it because there's no transition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8j900hz0/1/).

Please look at the [transition property link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition.asp) also.

Your clock was rotating 360 degrees, which means after you hovered on it, you were going to get the same result. To look at the clock rotating, you would have to add a css `transition` property.

This is the updated code.

```
#clock {
    border-radius: 100px;
    height: 79px;
    width: 79px;
    transition: 2s; /*or however many seconds you want it*/
    background: url('https://s3.postimg.io/3k6hhoafn/download.png');
}
#clock:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation on why my clock wasn't rotating.

Answer (score 2):

You have to give transition timing to see the rotation. your code is working.

```
transition: all 1s ease;
```

```css
#clock {
  border-radius: 100px;
  height: 79px;
  width: 79px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  background: url('https://s3.postimg.io/3k6hhoafn/download.png');
}
#clock:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="clock"></div>
</body>
```

Here is the working JSFiddle version:
https://jsfiddle.net/8j900hz0/2/

Answer (score 1):

Add `transition` to the `#clock` id.

```
#clock {
    border-radius: 100px;
    height: 79px;
    width: 79px;
    background: url('https://s3.postimg.io/3k6hhoafn/download.png');
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .8s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;
}
```